# 2 form submit in the same data

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I want to create 2 form submit, first button for save data, and the second button for backup.
If i click 'Save Data' button, it's work, but if i click 'Save Data as Backup' it's not work.

How to save data as backup with this my code ?

```
<?=form_open('action/saveData')?>
<?=form_open('action/saveDataasBackup')?>
<label>Your Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name">
<input type="submit" value="Save Data">
<?=form_close();?>
<input type="submit" value="Save Data as Backup">
<?=form_close();?>
```

Thanks anyway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forms can't be nested [HTML5 working draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/forms.html#the-form-element)

I would suggest you to use a single form in this case. When you receive form at back end, you can check weather to save the data or to back it up. You can achieve such functionality by adding the `name` attribute. Your form be like this:

```
<?=form_open('action/saveData')?>
<label>Your Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name">
<input type="submit" name="save" value="Save Data">
<input type="submit" name="backup" value="Save Data as Backup">
<?=form_close();?>
```

In controller method you can check like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['save'])){
    //perform save operation
}
if(isset($_POST['backup'])){
    //perform backup operation
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Forms can't be nested. You can use ajax or any other method to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following line only once at the end only.

```
<?=form_close();?>
```

Comment: NO Raja, It will not work. Since, Nested `<form></form>` are not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

you can not take form within form either seperate both form or use javascript in single form and change the action and then submit.

Answer (score 0):

Though you can have several  elements in one HTML page, you **cannot nest** them.

```
<?=form_open('action/saveData')?>
 <label>Your Name</label>
 <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name">
 <input type="submit" name="save" value="Save Data">
 <input type="submit" name="backup" value="Save Data as Backup">
<?=form_close();?>
```

**saveData (Controller)**

```
In this controller, Save Data and Create One Backup Also.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like below , why you use two form , if you want to add data in two table you can use like below example

**View file**

```
<?=form_open('action/saveData')?>
<label>Your Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name">
<input type="submit" value="Save Data">
<?=form_close();?>
```

**Model file**

```
Class Test extends CI_Model
{
    function insert_tbl1($data)
    {
        $this->db->insert('tbl_tbl1', $data);
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    }
    function insert_tbl2($data)
    {
        $this->db->insert('tbl_tbl2', $data);
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    }
}
```

**Controller file**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Action extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Test');
    }

    public function saveData()
    {
       if($_POST['save'] == "Save Data"){
        $data = array('test1' => $_POST['name']);
        $insert_tbl1 = $this->test->insert_tbl1($data);
        $insert_tbl2 = $this->test->insert_tbl2($data);
       }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only one form can be submitted at one time . you are not allowed to use form with in form according to html5 rules. instead of using two forms create only one form and place two submit buttons in it. one submit as a save data and other for save as a backup. both buttons will work fine in this way.